# Independent probability of events

Tags: probability

Suppose that the probability that you will drop a penny on the ground is 1/5, and the probability that you will find a penny on the ground today is 1/4. If the two events are independent, what is the probability that at least one of the two events will occur?

First I tried simply $1/5+1/4$ which was incorrect. Then I tried $( 1/5 \cdot 100)+ (1/4 \cdot 100)$, which was was incorrect as well. The correct answer is $2/5$ or $40\%$.

Comment: What do you know?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I don’t understand your question

Comment: Hint: it is often easier to work with the complement.  In this case, what is the probability that neither event occurs?

Comment: Do you know what independence means?  Do you know how to compute the probability that event $E$ or event $F$ occurs?

Comment: @user9513164 Here is an extended version of my question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Comment: @lulu thanks! The answer is 40% I don’t understand how

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes I know what independent events are

Comment: I get 45% hence I am confused

Comment: Please edit your post to include your calculation.

Comment: It sounds like you simply added the probabilities of the two events, which means you have counted those cases in which both events occur twice.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig can you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you did so that we do not have to speculate.  It makes it easier to address any errors you made.  Including your work and an explanation of where you are stuck is also expected on this site.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If two events, $A$ and $B$, are **independent** then the probability that *both* occur is $$Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$$.

If two events, $A$ and $B$, are **mutually exclusive** then the probability that *at least one* occurs is $$Pr(A\cup B)=Pr(A)+Pr(B)$$.

Do not confuse independence with mutual exclusivity, they are very different things.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but I think I got it 1 drop but not pick 1/5x3/4, 2 pick but not drop 1/4x4x5=4/20,3 drop and pick 1/5x1/4=1/20. Adding all 3/20+4/20+1/20 =8/20

Comment: Once you correct your typos, yes that is one way to look at it.  Another way to look at it is as suggested looking at the complement event and subtracting away from one, in this case not finding and not dropping, yielding the calculation $1-\frac{3}{4}\times\frac{4}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$.  Yet another way of looking at it is via inclusion exclusion as appearing below.

Comment: That is correct.  However, you should edit your question to show your work rather than placing your work in the comments where it might be missed.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks, I will do that next time. It’s my first time here

Comment: Since you have not explained what you have tried in the question, your question is likely to be closed, as per site rules.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig is this how I am supposed to ask a question?

Comment: That is better.  You could also have included your correct attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**
$$P(\text{drop or find penny})=P(\text{drop a penny})+P(\text{find a penny})-P(\text{drop and find a penny})$$

$$\iff P(D\cup F)=P(D)+P(F)-P(D\cap F)$$
Thus, 
$$=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{4}*\frac{1}{5}=\frac{2}{5}$$

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: @user9513164 remember to mark correctly!

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: @user9513164 the answer I gave you

Comment: @user9513164 Site guidelines are explained in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).  In particular, you may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

> First, I tried simply $1/5 + 1/4$, which was incorrect.

Let's see why.

Suppose we want to find $\Pr(A \cup B)$.

[image: Venn_diagram_for_two_sets]

If we simply add $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$, we will have added $\Pr(A \cap B)$ twice, once for each set in which the intersection is contained.  We only want to include $\Pr(A \cap B)$ once, so we must subtract it from $\Pr(A) + \Pr(B)$ to find $\Pr(A \cup B)$, that is
$$\Pr(A \cup B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$$

You did not subtract the probability that both events occurred from the sum of the probabilities that the individual events occurred.

> Then I tried $\frac{1}{5} \cdot 100 + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 100$, which was incorrect as well.

You made two mistakes here.  The first is described above.  The other is that you meant to multiply by $100\%$ rather than $100$.  Multiplying by $100$ gives you a probability greater than $1$.

> The probability that you will drop a penny on the ground is $1/5$; the probability that you will find a penny on the ground today is $1/4$.  If the two events are independent, what is the probability that at least one of the two events will occur?

**Method 1:**  Let $D$ be the event that you drop a penny; let $F$ be the event that you find a penny.  Then 
$$\Pr(D \cup F) = \Pr(D) + \Pr(F) - \Pr(D \cap F)$$
Since events $D$ and $F$ are independent, $\Pr(D \cap F) = \Pr(D)\Pr(F)$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D \cup F) & = \Pr(D) + \Pr(F) - \Pr(D \cap F)\\
              & = \Pr(D) + \Pr(F) - \Pr(D)\Pr(F)\\
              & = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} - \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
            & = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{20}\\
            & = \frac{4}{20} + \frac{5}{20} - \frac{1}{20}\\
            & = \frac{8}{20}\\
            & = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

**Method 2:**  We subtract the probability that neither event occurs from $1$. Let $D$ and $F$ be defined as above.
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D^C \cup F^C) & = 1 - \Pr(D \cup F)\\
                  & = 1 - [\Pr(D) + \Pr(F) - \Pr(D \cap F)]\\
                  & = 1 - \Pr(D) - \Pr(F) + \Pr(D \cap F)\\
                  & = 1 - \Pr(D) - \Pr(F) + \Pr(D)\Pr(F) && \text{since $D$ and $F$ are independent}\\
                  & = 1 - \Pr(D) - \Pr(F)[1 - \Pr(D)]\\
                  & = [1 - \Pr(D)][1 - \Pr(F)]\\
                  & = \Pr(D^C)\Pr(F^C)
\end{align*}
Hence, the independence of events $D$ and $F$ implies the independence of their complements.  Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D^C \cap F^C) & = \Pr(D^C)\Pr(F^C)\\
                  & = [1 - \Pr(D)][1 - \Pr(F)]\\
                  & = \left[1 - \frac{1}{5}\right]\left[1 - \frac{1}{4}\right]\\    
                  & = \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\\
                  & = \frac{3}{5}
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
P(E \cup F) & = 1 - P(D^C \cap F^C)\\ 
            & = 1 - \frac{3}{5}\\
            & = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

**Method 3:** We justify the solution you provided in the comments.  Let $D$ and $F$ be as above.
$$\Pr(D \cup F) = \Pr(D \cap F^C) + \Pr(D^C \cap F) + P(D \cap F)$$
Since $D$ and $F$ are independent, $\Pr(D \cap F) = \Pr(D)\Pr(F)$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D)\Pr(F^C) & = \Pr(D)[1 - \Pr(F)]\\
               & = \Pr(D) - \Pr(D)\Pr(F)\\
               & = \Pr(D) - \Pr(D \cap F) && \text{since $D$ and $F$ are independent}\\   
               & = \Pr(D \cap F^C)
\end{align*}
Hence, the independence of events $D$ implies the independence of $D$ and $F^C$.  Interchanging the roles of $D$ and $F$ in the above argument shows the independence of $D^C$ and $F$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(D \cup F) & = \Pr(D \cap F^C) + \Pr(D^C \cap F) + \Pr(D \cap F)\\
              & = \Pr(D)\Pr(F^C) + \Pr(D^C)\Pr(F) + \Pr(D)\Pr(F)\\
              & = \Pr(D)[1 - \Pr(F)] + [1 - \Pr(D)]\Pr(F) + \Pr(D)\Pr(F)\\
              & = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left[1 - \frac{1}{5}\right] + \left[1 - \frac{1}{4}\right]\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\\
              & = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\\
              & = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{3}{20} + \frac{1}{20}\\
              & = \frac{4}{20} + \frac{3}{20} + \frac{1}{20}\\
              & = \frac{8}{20}\\
              & = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}